# TypeError: create_bool(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:

Tags: python

please help me solve this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ADz-TECH_AIH _PC/PycharmProjects/Computer_Vision/OurAwsomePoseProject.py", line 7, in <module>
    detector = pm.poseDetector()
  File "C:\Users\ADz-TECH_AIH _PC\PycharmProjects\Computer_Vision\PoseEstimationModule.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.pose = self.mpPose.Pose(self.mode, self.upBody, self.smooth,
  File "C:\Users\ADz-TECH_AIH _PC\PycharmProjects\Computer_Vision\venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\pose.py", line 146, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\ADz-TECH_AIH _PC\PycharmProjects\Computer_Vision\venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 258, in __init__
    self._input_side_packets = {
  File "C:\Users\ADz-TECH_AIH _PC\PycharmProjects\Computer_Vision\venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 259, in <dictcomp>
    name: self._make_packet(self._side_input_type_info[name], data)
  File "C:\Users\ADz-TECH_AIH _PC\PycharmProjects\Computer_Vision\venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 513, in _make_packet
    return getattr(packet_creator, "create_" + packet_data_type.value)(data)
TypeError: create_bool(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: bool) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Invoked with: 0.5
```

this my code:

```
import cv2
import time
import PoseEstimationModule as pm

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
pTime = 0
detector = pm.poseDetector()
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findPose(img)
    lmList = detector.findPosition(img, draw=False)
    if len(lmList) != 0:
        print(lmList[14])
        cv2.circle(img, (lmList[14][1], lmList[14][2]), 15, (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime
        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (70, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
                    (255, 0, 0), 3)
        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

i new to python so i can't solve this
please help me everyone
i trying to make opencv project

Comment: Looks like the bug is in `PoseEstimationModule`, not in your code.

Comment: Specifically, I think it's passing a non-boolean arg to `mpPose.Pose()` where a boolean is expected.

Answer (score 0):

`import PoseEstimationModule as pm`

Make sure you are giving these defaults in the above module if you are creating your module or else you can see the code of mediapipe.python.solutions.pose,

```
class poseDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, modComplexity=1, smooth=True, eSegmentation=False, sSegmentation=True, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        '''Code Here'''
        self.pose = self.mpPose.Pose(self.mode, self.modComplexity, self.smooth, self.eSegmentation, self.sSegmentation, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        '''Rest CODE'''
```

Then use this again,

`detector = pm.poseDetector()`

You can also watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01sAkU_NvOY&t=4105s). It gave me the same error, but I did the above changes in the module file and was able to run it successfully.